# Out of Bounds when I want to generate a graph In MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I habe a little problem with my code:

```
X=[0, 2.5];
P(:,1)=0.1;
N=length(X);
for n=1:N
    for t=1:10
        P(n,t+1)=X(n)*P(n,t)*[1-P(n,t)];
    end
end

plot(t,P)
```

The computer answer me :

```
??? Attempted to access P(2,1); index out of bounds because
size(P)=[1,101].

Error in ==> test at 7
    P(n,t+1)=X(n)*P(n,t)*[1-P(n,t)];
```

I do not know how to solve it, but at final, I want to produce something similar of that : 
(picture link) : http://hpics.li/57b346a

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
P(:,1)=0.1;
```

means that `P` will be 1x1.  You need to initialise `P` to the correct size; something like:

```
P = 0.1 * ones(N,11);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but now when I realize that, the computer tell me that: What is the problem with my Plot ? 
??? Error using ==> plot
Vectors must be the same lengths.

Error in ==> test at 10
plot(t,P)